# How can I add --no-verify option to a commit using git gem?

Tags: ruby, git, github, githooks

I'm using the 'git' gem from rubygems.org to interact with a git repository.  Our company has recently added git hooks on commit that are getting in the way. I'd like to at least temporarily skip the git hooks to allow automation to continue working. On the command line I can use `git commit --no-verify` but can't find a way to do this using the git gem.  Is there a way to skip the commit checks with the git gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as we can see from its [source](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git/blob/master/lib/git/lib.rb)

```
def commit(message, opts = {})
  arr_opts = []
  arr_opts << "--message=#{message}" if message
  arr_opts << '--amend' << '--no-edit' if opts[:amend]
  arr_opts << '--all' if opts[:add_all] || opts[:all] 
  arr_opts << '--allow-empty' if opts[:allow_empty]
  arr_opts << "--author=#{opts[:author]}" if opts[:author]

  command('commit', arr_opts)
end
```

the gem only allows for a few options for `commit`.

You could possibly monkey-patch it though, as the source code seems very easy to read.

Comment: I can see how easy it would be to add.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have added the --no-verify option to the commit and push methods in this fork on github [richmi/ruby-git](https://github.com/richmi/ruby-git/tree/no-verify). A pull request has been submitted.